# Control a php script that consumes twitter's streaming api in shared hosting

Tags: api, search, twitter, streaming, shared-hosting

I'm beginning in the process to implement some code to use twitter "streaming api". I've been reading and learned that it is a one-time connection, kept alive, that is fed by twitter when some updates appear (or something like that), right?

**Well, does anyone know how should I do to control a php script in a shared hosting environment so I can start and stop -at my own will- monitoring tweets with this api?**

I haven't found (yet) info about how to do this with php and shared hosting, and don't want to:

*1) kill the shared server and make my hosting provider disable my account*

*2) exceed the connection limits to stream.twitter.com and get my acc. banned*

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Rather a delay on my answering this and I assume you've probably given up or figured it out yourself.

I wasn't 100% sure on the question but I think what you were asking how you would stop and start a script that connects to twitter. I've briefly used the streaming api and found it very useful. Generally shared hosting is annoying as you are limited in what you are allowed to do so that you don't use more than your fair share of resources.

It's unlikely that you could get away with making a script and using it via your webbrowser as scripts will often be killed off after a minute or so. So maybe the best way to run the script is to use it via a cron script. Either make cron run "php -f /path/to/script.php" or "wget http://example.com/script.php". You'd have to have cron run this every minute or however often. I believe that if you reconnect to the streaming api a second time it immediately disconnects the first instance.

As for controlling it, I would make a second script that simply has an on/off switch. It would simply create a file or delete it and the original script would check for it's presence. It'd only connect to twitter if the file didn't exist.

As for twitter limits, I believe that you should be safe as long as you don't try to track too many (5000) users or too many (400?) keywords at once.

Comment: Great. Do you know a php script to implement Streaming API? I guess that rather than creating a 1min cron it would be better to set it hourly, right? because I thought the streaming api connection was persistent, and thought too much connections would ban the instance? Thanks again

Comment: My only suggestion would be to look at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php or just use curl, the output from twitter is quite easy to parse.

As for my 1 minute cron idea, I only suggest that as cheapo shared hosting tends not to allow processes for an hour at a time. If yours does then, yes, doing it hourly just to make sure that if it breaks it's is only broken for a relatively short time seems like a good plan.